# tail command not updating output for debug files

Tags: linux, debugging, tail, command, debug

I know that tail -f /var/log/messages will be keep updating on screen as the contents of file gets updated.
But when I tried the same thing with a debug file system's file it is not working , any idea?

I tried ftrace and tried this:  tail -f trace it is not working ?

Note, I can see the contents actually getting by using watch -n1 cat trace.

Comment: The thing is, `tail -f` only works with files which are appended to. Maybe your debug file is not appended but overwritten with every run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuously monitor logs with tail that are occasionally rotated](https://serverfault.com/questions/53699/continuously-monitor-logs-with-tail-that-are-occasionally-rotated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tail -f` works on the file descriptor, not on the file name. If the file is being overwritten, or deleted and re-created,  `tail -f` won't be able to track that.

In gnu tail there's the option `--follow=name` or `-F` which will track the file name rather than the inode/file descriptor.